# Get Windows version in WinRT, Windows8(10) application

Tags: vb.net, windows, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-10

The question is straightforward.

I am using VB.Net to develop Windows8.1(+10) application.

And, I want to detect if the OS version is 8.1 or 10. Not even want to know other versions like XP, 7 and 8.

BUT, `Environment.OsVersion` is deprecated,

cannot access into Registry in Windows8 APP(it's a policy even it's possible),

cannot generate custom manifest(blocked) file to retrieve version info,

cannot use 'Kernel32.dll'(policy problem) to extract.

How can I get the Windows version in Windows8.1 or Windows10 Store application?

Thanks.

---

**Appended:**

1. I want to retrieve Windows version (whether it is 8.1 or 10)
2. which is important for manipulating Live Tile.
3. not altering critical behavior or something mentioned in comment. 
   the Windows metro app provides slightly different method to pin tiles in Start Menu, which is very annoying to handle without knowing Windows version. Anyway, it is not the main topic.
4. VB.Net or C# code would be very appreciated.
   It is not a 'give me the working code' thing.
5. This issue is not just on me,
   it is also ongoing topic on other sites:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678606/Part-Overcoming-Windows-s-deprecation-of-GetVe

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?776481-Get-OS-version-Windows-8-1-does-not-detect

only thing is that either the solution is based on C++ or not applicable to Windows 8.1(metro app).

Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Programs should not alter their behavior based on the operating system version number. This is the single largest source of compatibility bugs.

Comment: What do you want to know for? Is it for telemetry or something else?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this affects how you manipulate the Live Tile?

Comment: @RaymondChen There are two different things. First. Windows8.1 always shows a small icon on the SecondaryTiles lower left while Windows10 does not. When I create SecondaryTiles as images, I want to consider the space of the icon. Second. "RequestCreateAsync" method does not require any prompt on Windows10 while "RequestCreateAsync" always shows a prompt in Windows8.1 which makes crashes while running on BackgroundWorks. "RequestCreateForSelectionAsync" is the alternative method which is intended to show prompt to users.

Comment: You shouldn't put anything valuable in the lower left corner, because who knows, even though Windows 10 doesn't put the icon there, maybe Windows 11 will put it back. Also, you should assume that any method named RequestXxx can display a prompt. Therefore, don't call it from a background thread.

Comment: @RaymondChen I really appreciate your advice. But that's the secondary thing for me now, and that is not the answer. I do want to know the version of current Windows. That's the question. If assuming Windows 11 will pull back it, then I make the app to leave some space for the virtually existing icon if the version is not 10. Also, in examples of background task for tiles, they use the Request something method, which I fully understand its potential problem. Then, I want to know how to check the version after all. Thanks.

Comment: But what if version 11 decides to leave the space blank? You have no idea what version 11 is going to do. It might put something in the corner. It might not. You therefore should play it safe just in case. As for Request: You simply cannot call it from a background thread. You aren't supposed to do it even in Windows 10.

Comment: @RaymondChen Then how am I suppose to deal with the icon space? Should I not to use the bottom part of the Live Tile at all because of that? If there is no solution for knowing Windows version, I just have to leave the icon space as a dead space. And, yes, I understand about 'request' method. But as I wrote before, my question is not 'can I use [request] method in Windows10 which works fine but not feel comfortable to use?'. Thanks for the guideline of usage, but I just want to know how to detect the version..

Comment: You can use the bottom corner of the Live Tile. Just don't put anything important there, because it might be covered by a logo. Not sure what you're saying about "Request". The rule for "Request" is that you cannot call it from a background thread, regardless of OS version.

Comment: @RaymondChen Okay, then how can I retrieve Windows version after all? That's the point. I asked about it in every comment. Okay, I won't use 'request' method, I won't put important thing on the bottom corner of LiveTile, but might put less important thing which probably be covered by icon in Windows8 inevitably, because you said that I can use that bottom corner part even it's covered by icon unless it's an important thing. Your point is that detecting Windows version to altering the LiveTile design seems definitely worthless.

Comment: My point is that if you do things right, then you don't need to know the Windows version. You are trying to make your app do one thing on Windows 8.1 and another thing on Windows 10, but what will you app do on Windows 11?

Answer (score 2):

What you should be doing is checking whether the new methods are available. If they are available, use them, regardless of the operating system version. Example:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsMethodPresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView", "TryEnterFullScreenMode"))
{
     Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();   
}
```

Comment: I found out that Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation requires Windows10. Not working on Windows8.1.

Comment: @klados Prior to Windows 10, you have to call the method inside a try/catch. If the method isn't supported, you will get an exception. Not great, because there's no way to find out whether a method is supported except by trying to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any other way to do this, so here's my approach. (it's in C#, but you can easily translate it to Visual Basic)

The following property `IsWindows10` detects if a Windows 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1 app is running on a Windows 10 (including Windows 10 Mobile) device.

```
 #region IsWindows10

    static bool? _isWindows10;
    public static bool IsWindows10 => (_isWindows10 ?? (_isWindows10 = getIsWindows10Sync())).Value;

    static bool getIsWindows10Sync()
    {
        bool hasWindows81Property = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Any(r => r.Name == "DisplayName");
        bool hasWindowsPhone81Property = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Any(r => r.Name == "RawPixelsPerViewPixel");

        bool isWindows10 = hasWindows81Property && hasWindowsPhone81Property;
        return isWindows10;
    }
 #endregion
```

**How does it work?**

In Windows 8.1 the `Package` class has a `DisplayName` property, which Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't have.
In Windows Phone 8.1 the `DisplayInformation` class has a `RawPixelsPerViewPixel` property, which Windows 8.1 doesn't have.
Windows 10 (including Mobile) has both properties. That's how we can detect which OS the app is running on.